# Application of Cauchy product rule

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let be $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}$ two (absolute) convergent series. Then, the Cauchy product rule ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20in,French%20mathematician%20Augustin%20Louis%20Cauchy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20in,French%20mathematician%20Augustin%20Louis%20Cauchy.)) allows us to rearrange as follows:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}a_j2^{-(k-j)-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}2^{j-(k+1)}a_j$.

Hence, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}2^{j-(k+1)}a_j$ converges absolutely.

My tutor said that I mixed up the indices but I don't see where?

Comment: I was thinking of something else, sorry.

Comment: Looks fine (I wonder why the downvote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an intermediate step we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{\substack{k+j=n\\k,j\geq 0}}2^{-k-1}a_j\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^n2^{-(n-j)-1}a_j\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k2^{j-(k+1)}a_j}
\end{align*}
in accordance with OPs result. So, the calculation looks fine (+1).

Comment: thanks for the addtional remark Markus, my tutor really made me kind of insecure :S

Comment: @Philipp: You're welcome.